# .Net 6 Console app: WebApplication.CreateBuilder vs Host.CreateDefaultBuilder

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, console-application

I'm looking into .NET 6, and wanted to build a simple console application, with some dependency injection.

From what i can read, a lot has been done to make the startup (now just program) file, more readable.
What does confuse me a bit is, that all improvements seems to have been made to WebApplication.CreateBuilderpart used in API projects, and not the Host.CreateDefaultBuilder.
As mentioned in this [blog](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-2-comparing-webapplicationbuilder-to-the-generic-host/)

Microsofts own [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0), also only seems to mention WebApplication.

To me it seems like WebApplication is only for web projects, like an API, and i can't find anything that confirms og debunks that.

Is it okay to use WebApplication in a console application, or should i rely on Host, and keep the stacked lambda expressions ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`WebApplication.CreateBuilder()` is only used for web/api applications like the name implies `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()` is used to build a generic host (without web services, middleware etc) which you can use to build anything other than webhost.

See for example [.NET Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host) which has not changed.

Its true that it feels a bit awkward to build console apps and/or backgroundservices at the moment.

Comment: So we can't use the new minimal console template if we want to use IoC and add hostedservices? I am trying to wrap my head around this. I liked the state of it before because it looked the same, but now it is diverging a lot if i can't use the new minimal approach.

Comment: @mslot well it would be weird if the console template contained a whole lot of 'clutter' like that. But no - there is no 'console with di and all nice things asp.net core' template. This is sad and again - at the moment creating something like a background service (which would be a console app incl. DI and whatnot) feels weird.

I've created my own bootstrapper for this (but then i also wanted to have the same logging setting for all apps and so on) that constructs a generic host. I then have derived classes that construct a webapplication or background app etc.

Comment: Create an aspnet app build it dont run it

Answer (score 3):

This is a great reference that I use for using DI in a console application:
[Tutorial: Use dependency injection in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-usage)

Even though we're talking about console applications, DI gives you so many great options to manage hosting the app, and like any .NET application, when your application gets complex with many classes needing to share the same classes and configurations, even those sent in as CLI arguments, then DI really pays off.