# ConfigureWebHost() is not supported by WebApplicationBuilder.Host. Use the WebApplication returned by WebApplicationBuilder.Build() instead" error

Tags: c#, .net

I have just upgraded a dotnet core 3 api application to a 6.

So before, I had a startup.cs file with a ConfigureServices and a Configure method.

In order to not accidently break anything, and also perhaps save myself from doing work, I wanted to keep the startup.cs file.

So where I before used createdefaultbuilder, like this:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
    }
```

But now, I need to call "createBuilder" instead, and now my program.cs looks like this, where I try to use startup.cs by calling "ConfigureWebHostDefaults" on the host instead.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static WebApplicationBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        var webApplicationOptions = new WebApplicationOptions() { ContentRootPath = AppContext.BaseDirectory, Args = args, ApplicationName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName };
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(webApplicationOptions);
        
        builder.Host.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
        builder.Host.UseWindowsService();

        return builder;
    }
```

However, when I try to build and run, the "ConfigureWebHostDefaults", this error comes back at me:

> ConfigureWebHost() is not supported by WebApplicationBuilder.Host. Use
> the WebApplication returned by WebApplicationBuilder.Build() instead.'

Which seems like a pretty obvious instruciton, I just need to call "ConfigureWebHostsDefaults" on the built "WebApplicationBuilder".

But "WebApplication" has no definition for anything called "ConfigureWebHostDefaults", "Usestartup" or a field called "Host"

So it's entirely unclear to me what the error is trying to tell me.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 6):

In case you are trying to configure Kestrel in `ConfigureWebHostDefaults`, it can be done through `builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel` instead, this won't throw an error:

```cs
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
   serverOptions.Listen(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 44380, listenOptions =>
   {
       listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
       listenOptions.UseHttps("self.pfx", "123qwe");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` instead of `var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(webApplicationOptions)`.
For difference please check that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70345911/14095048). In your case should work well.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This question was also posted on reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/zf1z7u/configurewebhost_is_not_supported_by/), and the answer from davidfowl on that thread is the correct one. I'm sharing it here so others that find this thread like myself can get the correct answer.

You can't call the `UseStartup<Startup>();` method anymore, instead you manually call your startup methods like this.

```cs
var startup = new Startup();
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

var app = builder.Builder();

startup.Configure(app);

app.Run();
```

Here's the link davidfowl shared to the Microsoft documentation explaining all this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-startup-with-the-new-minimal-hosting-model